# How can I use distinct only for certain table variables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use 'distinct' on all Home(table name) variables however i am also selecting other variables from other tables too. How can i only choose distinct select for Home variables/or only certain columns?

This query is using distinct for ALL variables including the ones for anotherTable.

Here is my query

```
 SELECT distinct f.q_id, f.var2, f.var3, f.var4, m.var22
 FROM Home f, anotherTable m
 WHERE f.q_id = m.q_id
```

I tried wrapping variables individually with distinct but that will not allow me to make my distinct preference on variables.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  If you don't want duplicated data from certain columns, which should be displayed?

Comment: @sgeddes I just need distinct on the home variables so f.q_id, f.___, etc

Comment: So what value should `var22` return if multiple exists in `anotherTable`?  The `min`, `max`, something else?  Hence the reason sample data and expected results would help.  I'd also suggest using a `join` rather than commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: What do you expect to have happen when there are several rows with the same q_id and different var2s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `group by`:

```
SELECT f.q_id, f.var2, f.var3, f.var4, MAX(m.var22)
FROM Home f JOIN
     anotherTable m
     ON f.q_id = m.q_id 
GROUP BY f.q_id, f.var2, f.var3, f.var4;
```

Comment: lindoff beautiful! works great. however, i lose the column for 'var22' name. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to select DISTINCT data only from Home and ALL from anotherTable:

```
SELECT t.q_id, t.var2, t.var3, t.var4, m.var22
FROM anotherTable m
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT 
             f.q_id, f.var2, f.var3, f.var4 FROM Home f) t ON t.q_id = m.q_id
```

Comment: getting duplicates :(

Comment: Add SUM or MAX function on the m.var22 column as per the requirement, otherwise you can post data and it's output.